# Creating helppage for a webapi c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a help page for webapi in C#. I am using `GetApiExplorer` and `ParameterDescriptor.ParameterType.GetProperties()`.
Everything is good but when the input is a list of complex type. Then the output that I get is of list not the complex type. How to get the complex type of the list input of web api.

```
 foreach (var subProperty in parameter.ParameterDescriptor.ParameterType.GetProperties())
{
    APIEndPointParameter _APIEndPointSubParameter = new APIEndPointParameter(subProperty.Name, "", "", false, subProperty.PropertyType.ToString(), null);
    _APIEndPointParameter.SubParameters.Add(_APIEndPointSubParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
I got the type of list object then created the instance. Then objInstance.GetType().GetProperties() to get the properties of the class.

```
 var properties = parameter.ParameterDescriptor.ParameterType.GetProperties();
 var _prop = properties[2];
 Type _objType = _prop.PropertyType;
 object objInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(_objType);

foreach (var subProperty in objInstance.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
      APIEndPointParameter _APIEndPointSubParameter = new APIEndPointParameter(subProperty.Name, "", "", false, subProperty.PropertyType.ToString(), null);
      _APIEndPointParameter.SubParameters.Add(_APIEndPointSubParameter);
   }
```